# Find the date of the oldest messages in gmail

Tags: mailkit

How can one find the date of the oldest messages in a gmail account?

If i do this

> var messages = imapFolder.Fetch(0, -1,  MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId |
>   MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate).ToList();

I get a list of uid's and dates, but they don't appear to be sorted in date order.

And the last row is not the oldest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the older a message is the earlier in the list it will be. In other words, the oldest message in a folder will generally be the *first* message, not the last.

That said, you could use the `MessageSorter` extension methods to sort your list.

```
var messages = imapFolder.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate ).ToList();
messages.Sort (new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.Date });
```

or, if you want them in reverse date order:

```
messages.Sort (new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.ReverseDate });
```

Comment: I found that specifying the 0, -1 does not find the oldest message if you look in the INBOX. Not sure if this is because google moved messages out of my inbox.  But the oldest date was found by specifying 0,-1 for the "All Mail" folder.